# Angle a point subtends a finite length line at varying parallel and perpendicular distances.

Tags: geometry

What is the formula for the angle that a point subtends a finite length line at varying parallel and perpendicular distances?

This is shown on the left hand side of the picture below. I want to find angle $\theta$ for a given D, x and y.

[image]

I guessed that I could find the answer by taking away the angle of the tall triangle from the angle of the short triangle. This gives the formula:

$$\theta=atan( x/(y-(D/2)) ) – atan(x/(y+(D/2)))$$

But when [plotted on a graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vpomda5cf5) this doesn't look correct. (On this graph $\theta$ is shown by the y axis, the parallel distance from the center of the finite line is shown as x, and the size of the line and the perpendicular distance from the line are shown as D and z, and can be changed by moving the slider). This graph shows that there is a very sudden change once the point moves above the line, which seems strange. If I picture the point moving from $y = 0$ up to $y = \inf$ I can picture the angle changing values smoothly, and there are no sudden jumps.

What is the correct formula for this?

---

*Edit: The capital Y in the picture should also be a lower case y. Also, just to clarify, in the graph shown in the link, the y shown in the picture is the x shown in the graph, and the x shown in the picture is the z in the graph.*

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are correct, but you made an error in desmos calculator: remove absolute values from denominators and the graph will become almost OK.

Dicontinuity is caused by your point passing the object edge, that is one of tans skipping between minus to plus infinity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "Dicontinuity is caused by your point passing the object edge, that is one of tans skipping between minus to plus infinity". But this wont happen if I measure the angle in the real world. The angle shouldn't be negative for points within the objects edges. Is there a formula that will give me the correct answer for all points?

Comment: Also, I think I've just worked out why my calculation doesn't work. My logic that $\theta$ equals the short triangles angle minus the tall triangles angle only holds for when the point is outside the objects edge. I need a new formula that works for every point.

Comment: Try measuring angles from the horizontal line on your drawing instead of vertical one, thus calculating $\arctan \frac{\Delta y}x$ instead of $\arctan \frac x{\Delta y}$. This way you avoid $\frac\pi 2$ angles, which cause the weird $\arctan$ behaviour.